# How to fill textbox with selected JSON using select form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Help, how to select JSON using selectform and fill some textbox with selected JSON from controller.

For example when i select 1st item in selectform 
**textbox1=data1, textbox2=data1, texbox3=data3** if i select 2nd item from selectform **textbox1=data2, textbox2=data2, texbox3=data2** and so on.

```
VIEW

<script>
         var url = $('.url-location').data('url');
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url + "Projects/GetProjects",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (result)
                {
                    var project = '<option value="">Please Select Project List</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                        project += '<option value="' + result.data[i].ProjectID + '">' + result.data[i].ProjectID + '</option>';
                        var data1 = result.data[i].ProjectID;
                        var data2 = result.data[i].Description;
                        var data3 = result.data[i].ConReference;
                    }
                    $("#ProjectList").html(project);
                    $('#ProjectList').change(function ()
                    {
                        $('#ProjectNo').val(data1);
                        $('#ProjectName').val(data2);
                        $('#CustomerPONo').val(data3);
                    });
                }
            });
         });
    </script>

CONTROLLER

public ActionResult GetProjects(string username)
        {
            bool morePages = false;
            ProjectListDataSet rscProjct = null;
            try
            {
                rscProjct = _connection.ProjectSvc.GetList("Company = 'CBM'", 0, 0, out morePages);
                List<object> result = new List<object>();
                foreach (DataRow dr in rscProjct.ProjectList.Rows)
                {
                    result.Add(new {
                        ProjectID = dr["ProjectID"],
                        Description = dr["Description"],
                        ConReference = dr["ConReference"],
                        StartDate = dr["StartDate"],
                        ConCustNum = dr["ConCustNum"],
                        Company = dr["Company"]
                    });
                }
                return Json(new { data = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                return Json(new { data = "", error = x.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of $('#ProjectNo').val(data1); use $('#ProjectNo').val(this.value);

Comment: @denny i do't now what you are trying to see because before if someone provide you the correct solution need proper picture of the query.